# Terminal + Plesk + New Directory

Tags: web, terminal, plesk

I am trying to transfer my new web files into an httpdocs_new folder. However, creating a new directory in plesk seems almost impossible - when I finally managed to figure out a way to create a new directory, I crashed my site and got a 500 - Internal Server Error. Is there a way I can create an httpdocs_new folder so once all my files are transferred into that folder, I can make the httpdocs -> httpdocs_old and the new folder httpdocs???

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Just copy your original `httpdocs/` to say `private/httpdocs_old` (in case you just need to backup the files). Now clean and replace all files in httpdocs/ with your new files.

Alternatively click your site name and type new folder name there (i.e. `httpdocs_new/`) and then upload all your new files there.